Sending Large Attachments Using MimeKit and MailKit
So basically I would want to send a email with an attachment greater than 25MB minimum, I have tried sending it as multiple attachments (breaking down the data into chunks), but that gives out an error saying "email size exceeded". Any other alternative I can use to obtain this functionality, for example can I change the size of the limitation?
Ive tried breaking the attachments into multiple parts/chunks in order to reduce the size of each attachment, but this ends up exceeding the size of the overall email and again producing the error.

"So basically I would want to send a email with an attachment greater than 25MB minimum" - yeah, don't. I sure as h hate it, when s/o sends me a huge mail. Send share-links to some file-sharing service, where receipients can download whatever is needed.

"can I change the size of the limitation?" - That in general is rarely a good idea. The limit is there for a reason in the first place. And: if you have a send-limit, wouldn't it be natural to assume receipients might have receive-limits?
